# Is there a generalisation of the first isomorphism from groups to group actions?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For groups, we have the first isomorphism theorem; this says that given any morphism $\alpha: G \to H$ in $Grp$, we have $G/Ker\alpha = Im G$.

Is there a generalization of this to group actions?

Comment: A group action $G \curvearrowright X$ can be equivalently thought of as a group homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ and thus the isomorphism theorem carries over.

Comment: Sort of. Look up the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that there is some kind of first isomorphism theorem already for sets. If $X$ and $Y$ are sets and $f: X \to Y$ is a map, then $R_f = \{(x,x') \in X \times X\:|\: f(x) = f(x')\}$ is an equivalence relation and $f$ factorizes as $X \to X/R_f \to Y$ where $X/R_f$ is the set of equivalence classes with respect to $R_f$, $X \to X/R_f$ maps an element $x \in X$ to its equivalence class $[x]$ and $X/R_f \to Y$ maps each equivalence class $[x]$ to $f(x)$ and by definition of $R_f$ this is well-defined and $X/R_f \to Y$ is injective.

Now, let $X$ and $Y$ be $G$-sets (sets with $G$-actions) and let $f: X \to Y$ a $G$-homomorphism between them (i.e. $f(g x) = g f(x)$ for all $x \in X$ and $g \in G$). Then the equivalence relation $R_f$ from above is compatible with the group action meaning $(x,x') \in R_f$ implies $(g x, gx') \in R_f$ for all $x,x' \in X$. It follows that the set of equivalence classes $X/R_f$ obtains a natural $G$-action and the induced map $X/R_f \to Y$ is an injective $G$-homomorphism, thus an isomorphism onto its image.

A special case of this is the orbit-stabilizer theorem. If $X$ is a $G$-set and $x \in X$, then considering $G$ as a $G$-set the map $\varphi_x : G \to X, g \mapsto gx$ is a $G$-homomorphism and $R_{\varphi_x}$ is given by $(g,g') \in R_{\varphi_x}$ iff $g^{-1}g' \in \text{Stab}_G(x)$, that is $R_{\varphi_x}$ is the equivalence relation coming from the subgroup $\text{Stab}_G(x)$ and $G/R_{\varphi_x}$ is simlpy the set of cosets $G/\text{Stab}_G(x)$ and $G/\text{Stab}_G(x) \to Gx$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: This looks like it ought to be the first isomorphism theorem for algebras, in the sense of universal algebra; group actions, ought to be a variety, as groups and sets are, and the additional axioms for an action are equational.

Comment: Yes, the isomorphisms theorems can be generalized to universal algebra, you might want to look at the Wikipedia article where this is explained.

Comment: @klupsch: it's looking at it that prompted my comment; but it was your proof that prompted me to find it! ;).